# 'SyntaxError' calling javascript function?

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

Anyone know why `Tool_AJAX.loadString("' + split[i] + '");` is not working?
Even though this line works fine ..

`split[i] = 'Hello'`

```
alert('Tool_AJAX.loadString("' + split[i] + '")');
Output: Tool_AJAX.loadString("Hello");
```

Heres the troublesome code ..

```
body += 
    '<tr>' +
        '<td><h4><a href="javascript:;" onclick="Tool_AJAX.loadString("' + split[i] + '");">' + split[i] + '</a></h4></td>' +
        '<td>Dummy</td>' +
        '<td>Dummy</td>' +
    '</tr>';


Error: SyntaxError: syntax error
Source File: http://localhost:8080/Tool/
Line: 1, Column: 32
Source Code:
Tool_AJAX.loadString(
```

`Tool_AJAX` is defined as ..

```
var Tool_AJAX = {
    loadString: function(string){
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'<td><h4><a href="javascript:;" onclick="Tool_AJAX.loadString("' + split[i] + '");">' + split[i] + '</a></h4></td>' +
```

This will end as

```
<td><h4><a href="javascript:;" onclick="Tool_AJAX.loadString("...");">...</a></h4></td>
```

The `onclick`-part is malformed because of the quotes.
If you can't separate the Javascript from the HTML use single quotes for the string between the brackets:

```
 '<td><h4><a href="javascript:;" onclick="Tool_AJAX.loadString(\'' + split[i] + '\');">' + split[i] + '</a></h4></td>' +
```

Comment: I was in the middle of typing almost exactly this.  :)  +1

Comment: This works perfect, thanks! The reason I'm embedding the HTML inside JavaScript is because its dymanic, I don't know how many `<tr>` elements will be loaded into the `split` array. Do you have a suggestion on how this separation could still be achieved given this constraint?

Comment: I haven't talk about the HTML in the Javascript. I've talked about the inline handler for the `onclick` event. Why not add a click handler on the table instead of one for each row.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Tool_AJAX.loadString("'" + split[i] + "'");
```

(Do you really need split[i] in quotes as argument?)

Answer (score 0):

Try `\"' + split[i] + '\"`. It should work.

Comment: Not quite.  The problem isn't JavaScript; it's that HTML is interpreting the quotes.  They need to be single quotes instead, or HTML-escaped like `&quot;`, so they don't cut off the attribute value.